# Django error the view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

For an ecommerce website trying to do this : When I click on order now button it should redirect to a payment url(the url takes a parameter order_id). But instead, I get error

> The view ecomapp.views.pay didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

I know this question been asked before but none of the solutions have helped me solve the problem.

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('',views.index,name="index"),
   path('about',views.about,name="about"),
   path('contact',views.contact,name="contact"),
   path('categories',views.categories,name="categories"),
   path('productdetail/<slug:slug>',views.productdetail,name="productdetail"),
   path('addtocart/<int:pro_id>',views.addtocart,name="addtocart"),
   path('cartview',views.cartview,name="cartview"),
   path("manage-cart/<int:cp_id>/",views.managecart, name="managecart"),
   path("emptycart",views.emptycart, name="emptycart"),
   path("checkout",views.checkout, name="checkout"),
   path("register",views.register, name="register"),
   path("login",views.login, name="login"),
   path("logout",views.logout, name="logout"),
   path("search",views.search, name="search"),
   path("adminlogin",views.adminlogin, name="adminlogin"),
   path("adminhome", views.adminhome, name="adminhome"),
   path("adminorderdetail/<int:pk>/", views.adminorderdetail,name="adminorderdetail"),
   path("pay", views.pay,name="pay")
]
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url="/login")
    def checkout(request):
        form = CheckoutForm(request.POST or None)
        cart_id = request.session.get("cart_id", None)
        if cart_id:
            cart_obj = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.instance.cart = cart_obj
                form.instance.subtotal = cart_obj.total
                form.instance.discount = 0
                form.instance.total = cart_obj.total
                form.instance.order_status = "Order Received"
                del request.session['cart_id']
                o = form.save()
                form = CheckoutForm()
                return redirect(reverse("pay") + "?o_id=" + str(o.id))
        else:
            cart_obj = None
        return render(request, "checkout.html", {'cart': cart_obj, 'form': form})
```

**pay**

```
 def pay(request):
            o_id = request.GET.get("o_id")
            orderr = Order.objects.get(id=o_id)
            order_amount = orderr.total*100
            order_currency = "INR"
            order = client.order.create(
                dict(amount=order_amount, currency=order_currency))
            context = {
                'order_id': order['id'],
                'amount': order['amount'],
                'key_id': key_id
            }
            return render(request, "pay.html", context)
```

**ERROR**

```
ValueError at /pay
The view ecomapp.views.pay didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/pay?o_id=63
Django Version: 4.0.1
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
The view ecomapp.views.pay didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Exception Location: C:\Users\hello\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 309, in check_response
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.6
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\hello\\Desktop\\PROOO\\ecomproject',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\hello\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 12 Jan 2022 14:50:01 +0000
```

Razorpay payment integration is used

Comment: Can you add your `urls.py` file?

Comment: From the code you shared, You don't set the key_id variable anywhere in the pay view.

Comment: Your form is valid?

Comment: @mirodil yes I added it

Comment: @NikitaKosych its value is already declared/assigned in my project

Comment: @Luiz yes its valid

Comment: @user123 why didn't you set id for pay url if it takes a parameter order_id?

Comment: @user123 When you run this code in debug, do you get up to return render line?

Comment: @NikitaKosych yes

Comment: When you browse the url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/pay?o_id=63 directly without the redirect, do you still get the same error? if so, these an issue with the pay view.

Can you wrap it with try/except and see what error do you get from it?